# Excel 2010 Pivot Table sorting dates in ascending order correctly, but not descending

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

Background:

- I'm working with Excel 2010.
- I have a pivot table connected to an excel data table (formatted as a
  range)
- I have a date/time field called "Date" that is at the daily level MM/DD/YYYY
- The field called "Date" is definitely stored as date/time. Type()=1.
- My pivot table uses the "Date" field as the row field. It summarizes a different metric as the value.
- I have several fields that filter the pivot that are controlled
  through slicers.
- I want the date field to sort descending, newest to oldest.

Problem:
Whenever I change a pivot table field using a slicer, the descending sort sort order breaks. It sorts the days out of order and the way I fix it is by sorting ascending and then sorting descending. That fix only until I change the pivot table filters using a slicer again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently the pivot tables only fail with descending order. They work with ascending order.

Comment: And the descending sort fixes/breaks with alternating changes. Select one slicer and the sort works, the next slicer selected will break the sort, the next slicer will fix, etc.